# Получить элемент в xml

Tags: c#, xml

Есть вот такой xml

```
<response>
<list>
<item>
<id>26</id>
<count>3</count>
</item>
<item>
<id>1</id>
<count>4</count>
</item>
<item>
<id>2</id>
<count>2</count>
</item>
<item>
<id>3</id>
<count>3</count>
</item>
</list>
</response>
```

Как к примеру получить count у элемента с id равным 2-вум?

Comment: Посмотрите использование XPath для чтения XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так, например:

```
response/list/item[id=2]/count
```

Как достать `value` у 'count', я думаю, Вы уже знаете

Comment: Не работает

Comment: [Пруф][1]. Кнопку "Test" нажмите


  [1]: http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/527e7aa7e86135702e6adecdffd4cd90

Comment: А что у Вас в `Data.text_get_auth`?

Comment: Это понятно, меня содержимое интересует. Там та xml, которую Вы в вопросе привели?

Comment: Да )))))))))))))))))))))

Comment: [Вот][1] на это взгляните. Скорее всего Вы что-то делаете не так


  [1]: http://ideone.com/cvLU1n

Comment: А можно  как то проверить существование этого элемента?

Answer (score 2):

Юзайте LINQtoXML. Примерно так:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("your path");            
var node = from i in doc.Element("response").Element("list").Elements()
           where i.Element("id").Value == "2"
           select i.Element("count").Value;
```